# where does the react context store values, and when will the value be cleaned?

Tags: reactjs

I know this questions seems like a little bit silly. But I just tried searching everywhere and seems like no one has ask this kind of question before.

Comment: Can you elaborate -- what is your motivation for learning this? React values use memory associated with the javascript process. When the process stops the memory is released.